# Adding grouped sum of one variable to the original data

Tags: count, aggregate, spss

My data look like:

```
Sample_ID Member_ID gender         relative_ID      relative_desc
1         11         male           1               Head
1         12         female         2               Partener
1         13         female         3               Child
1         14         female         3               Child
2         21         female         1               Head
2         22         male           3               Child
3         31         male           1               Head
3         32         female         2               Partener
4         41         male           1               Head
4         42         female         2               Partener
4         43         male           3               Child
4         44         male           3               Child
5         51         female         1               Head
5         52         female         3               Child
5         53         male           3               Child
5         54         male           3               Child
```

and many other columns..
what I want to know is how many child that each family has
and I did a lot of search and try to unpivot the relative_desc variable by :

```
COMPUTE Child = (relative_desc = "Child").
```

And then try to sum the aggregate with break of sample Id

```
DATASET DECLARE AggHouse.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE='AggHouse'
  /BREAK SAMPLE_ID
  /Child = SUM(Child).
```

this will move the sample id and number of child in each family into new dataset, what I did is merge the new sum column into the original dataset but I got a lot of missing data, any other suggestions?
thank you so much.

Comment: is there a way to do the same with R language ?

Comment: The answer is "yes" of course, but you should start a new question with an `R` tag to get code suggestions (after you search for existing answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate directly into the original dataset and save yourself work and troubles:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* mode=addvariables overwritevars=yes
  /BREAK SAMPLE_ID
  /Child = SUM(Child).
```

Note - the `overwritevars` subcommand lets you rewrite the `Child` variable with the sum. alternatively you could put the sum in a new variable like `SumChild`.

If you do prefer to aggregate to a new dataset and then reattach it back to the original dataset, please add to your post the syntax you used for that, so we can see what the problem was.

Comment: It work properly, I wasn't need to aggregate to a new data but I didn't know how to do it without that, Thank you so much

Comment: is there a way to do the same with R language ?